# Unable to uninstall GNOME Shell Extension 'Sensors'

Tags: uninstall, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I tried for over 2 hours to uninstall Sensors extension, but I just can't. This is what I tried so far:

Deleted both local's and system's GNOME extensions folder content, then reset GNOME Shell, the extension still appears.

I tried to uninstall it via the browser GNOME extension, and then it got deleted. But when I reset GNOME Shell, this extension is here again.

The command `ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` gives no result, and the command `ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` gives 3 results, the other 3 extensions that appear in Tweaks.

Here is the screenshot of that extension in Tweaks:
[image: Here is the screenshot of that extension]

Here is the screenshot of that extension in GNOME browser extension:
[image: Here is the screenshot of that extension in GNOME browser extension]

I can uninstall it from browser extension but it's pointless, as soon as I reset the GNOME Shell it comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a fix by myself, found that extension file in the location `/usr/local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and fixed it by deleting the extension's folder. Hope this helps for anyone having my issue.